# .htaccess rule: redirect parameter to filename

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect the following example:

http://www.mypage.tld/media/optivo/ch/de/?id=0805610075C6000

to

http://www.mypage.tld/media/optivo/ch/de/0805610075C6000.xml

So the parameter value should be the filename with an .xml extension

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=([^&]+)  
RewriteRule ^media/optivo/ch/de/$ $0%1.xml [L,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

# capture the value of id parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=([^&]+)
# for a .htaccess in root directory
RewriteRule ^media/optivo/ch/de/(?:index\.php)?$ $0%1.xml [L,R=permanent]
# for a .htaccess located in de subdirectory
#RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php)?$ %{REQUEST_URI}%1.xml [L,R=permanent]
```

Comment: From a .htaccess? Where is it located? Does Apache read .htaccess files (AllowOverride != None)? Can you add `DirectoryIndex disabled` to the .htaccess?

Comment: It is located in the root folder of the web-root directory. DirectoryIndex index.php